Am I correct in using lsmeans or emmeans
Good day,
I have some data I am trying to analyze and want to make sure I am doing so correctly. My data consists in a set of 10 samples which I inoculated with a pathogen in different days (I named these "Tests) and had a total of 3 "Tests", given sample availability, I had to randomize which samples where going to be inoculated in a given "Test" and included two controls to be present in all 3 "Tests".
The raw data would look something like this:
 Sample = c(1,2,3,4,5,C,8,4,5,6,7,C,8,9,1,6,3)
 Test=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
 Rating=c(1,1,4,4,3,0,1,4,3,4,3,0,2,4,1,4,3,0)

The data is just to represent my question, my actual data is much larger in sample size as well as dates and there was replications of a sample within the same Test, but wanted to show an idea of the design. So, as you can see there will be samples that would have been replicated in multiple tests and some that could have been replicated in just one, my control being present in all Tests for sure.
I want to know if its ok for me to run lsmeans on R to obtain a corrected average, the model being:
lm(Rating~ Sample + Test + Sample*Test) 

If so also if it would be correct to do a Tukey HSD analysis on it as well.
Thanks.

If your Test contains what amounts to replicate information, I think a model in the form of lm(Rating~Sample) is more appropriate. It is not very clear what you want to understand? Are you interested in the Rating obtained for different Samples, or in how of Sample, Test and their combination affects Rating, which is what your current formula models

My goal is to see how samples performed overall after inoculation (Rating), but given that I couldn't inoculate all samples in the same test and had to do different tests, that is why I thought of including "Test" as part of the model, my control being present in all the inoculation Tests to validate observe that it was consistently rating the same. But this was my assumption which comes from someone who is not as knowledgeable in statistics.

I would not include Test in the model. I do not know what your full data looks like but given the dataset you posted i would be careful, it seems that your Samples are a bit unbalanced (you have different numbers of observations for some sample) I think your statistical analysis will not be very robust and I am not sure if running it through Tukey or em/lsmeans. This is of course not the case if you actually have much larger n for each of your samples. https://stats.stackexchange.com/ would be the better place to ask about statistics
